# App service not listed in "Azure Web App for Containers" Task in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-appservice

I have an option to use one of the four app services available in Azure portal created under one subscription (in same resource group). I have created a Azure DevOps release pipeline with "Azure Web App for Containers" task (as I have to deploy docker based dotnet application which has the option to set image name). When I select my Service Connection name, none of the App service name were listed. How to find the reason?

When I try with "Azure App Service deploy" task it shows only "Web App for Containers (Linux)". Is it not available for windows ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the team project settings and then click on the **Service connections** Tab. And create a new ARM service endpoint, use 'Azure Resource Manager' endpoint type. Then select this new service connection.
2. Close all browsers, and open a new incognito/InPrivate window to try again.
3. Press F12 to check the whether there is any error in Network when you select the service connection.

Comment: Thanks Cece Dong. Yes I already created the service connection. My question is why no App Services were no listed when I select my service connection. But I checked in F12, no errors found.

Comment: I mean you could try to create a new service connection. The existing connection may have some issue to access the app service. Also, when you create new service connection, capture the network trace, to see whether there is any error.

Comment: I tried new service connection. But I didn't see any errors

Comment: So you can create the service connection successfully? Have you tried created a manual Service principal?

Comment: I tried Service Principal (automatic). When I try "Azure App Service deploy" task, I have selected App service type as "Web App on Windows". For that option only two App Service were displayed out of my four app services. When I select App Service type "Web App for Containers (Linux)", no app service were listed

Comment: Have you tried creating a new app service?